# Setting the access token on .register flask_client

Tags: python-3.x, flask, authlib

I've been searching for a while now in the documentation and DuckDuckGo but I can not find how to do this.

I want to set the token in the register function or somewhere else that gets it from a "database", So instead of having to login again I restore the old one. I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `fetch_token` function in your client, here is the documentation:

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html#fetch-user-oauth-token

Comment: Hello lepture, I'm trying to use this but when registering and using .get() afterwards I get an AttributeError.

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'authlib_oauth_token_facebook'`

In the register function like this:
`fetch_token=lambda: facebook_token,`
facebook_token is a dictionary that has acces_token and token_type.

Comment: I've found something else: _app_ctx_stack.top seems to be None inside remote_app.py